# Implementing searchview - gridview filter

Tags: java, android, gridview, searchview

I have simple question about searchview - I created searchview item in my menu, I have functional gridview, but I dont know how to finish my code in onCreateOptionMenu - it won't recognize my GridAdapter. Codes below

**MainActivity.java**

```
    package com.example.mp.basicsearch;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton;
import android.support.design.widget.Snackbar;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.SearchView;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.widget.GridView;

import com.mancj.materialsearchbar.MaterialSearchBar;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    GridView gridView;

    String[] values = {
            "Novinky",
            "Ihned",
            "Stranka"
    };

    int[] images = {
            R.drawable.ic_dots_vertical_black_48dp,
            R.drawable.ic_close_black_48dp,
            R.drawable.ic_history_black_48dp
    };

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        gridView = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.griview);
        GridAdapter gridAdapter = new GridAdapter(this, values, images);
        gridView.setAdapter(gridAdapter);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);




        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

And this is the code, I think I am supposed to add in **onCreateOptionsMenu**, but it doesn't work:

```
MenuItem item = menu.findItem(R.id.menuSearch);
        SearchView searchView = (SearchView)item.getActionView();

        searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(new SearchView.OnQueryTextListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {
                return false;
            }

            @Override
            public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText) {
                gridAdapter.getFilter().filter(newText);
                return false;
            }
        });
```

**gridAdapter** is my adapter of gridview, but it is shown RED, what is the think I don't get.
BTW: The app stops working even after adding those 2 lines in onCreateOptionsMenu:

```
MenuItem item = menu.findItem(R.id.menuSearch);
        SearchView searchView = (SearchView)item.getActionView()
```

**menu_main.xml**

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    tools:context="com.example.mp.basicsearch.MainActivity" >

    <item android:id="@+id/action_settings"
        android:title="@string/action_settings"
        android:orderInCategory="100"
        app:showAsAction="never" />

    <item
        android:id="@+id/menuSearch"
        android:title="Search"
        android:icon="@android:drawable/ic_menu_search"
        app:actionViewClass="android.widget.SearchView"
        app:showAsAction="always"

        />
</menu>
```

Comment: share your menu.xml file and also share crash log with question

Comment: Okay, added. Thanks for answering.

Answer (score 0):

your `gridadapter` variable is local to `onCreate`. Declare it outside OnCreate next to `gridview`. Then it will be accessible in `onCreateoptionsMenu`.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

GridView gridView;
GridAdapter gridAdapter;
```

and in  `onCreate` change `GridAdapter gridAdapter =` to `gridAdapter=`

```
 @Override
   protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    gridView = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.griview);
     gridAdapter = new GridAdapter(this, values, images);
    gridView.setAdapter(gridAdapter);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for answering, I have already tried this before. When it recognize the adapter, the getFilter in onQueryTextChange gets red..